# Adding timestamp to file downloaded with urllib.urlretrieve

Tags: python, urllib

I am using `urllib.urlretrieve` to download files, I would like to add something to check for changes before downloading. I already have something like the following:

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.site1.com/file.txt", r"output/file1.txt")
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.site2.com/file.txt", r"output/file2.txt")
```

Ideally i would like the script to check for changes (compare the last modified stamp?), ignore if same and download if newer, I need the script to add a timestamp to the filename.

Can anyone help?

I am new to programming (python is my first) so any criticism welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this seems to be quite hard to do in python, as you have to do everything yourself. Additionally the interface for `urlretrieve` is not very nice.

The following code should perform the necessary steps (adding the "If-Modified-Since" header if the file exists and adjusting the timestamp of the downloaded file):

```
def download_file(url, local_filename):
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    if os.path.isfile(local_filename):
        timestamp = os.path.getmtime(local_filename)
        timestr = time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT', time.gmtime(timestamp))
        opener.addheaders.append(("If-Modified-Since", timestr))
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    try:
        local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, local_filename, reporthook=status_callback)
        if 'Last-Modified' in headers:
            mtime = calendar.timegm(time.strptime(headers['Last-Modified'], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'))
            os.utime(local_filename, (mtime, mtime))
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        if e.code != 304:
            raise e
    urllib.request.install_opener(urllib.request.build_opener())  # Reset opener
    return local_filename
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. It's worth noting that you will need to import `urllib.request`, `time` and `calendar` (all of which are in the standard library), and possibly implement the `status_callback` function or remove the parameter for this code to work.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest approach for the timestamp in the filename is:

```
import time
'output/file_%d.txt' % time.time()
```

Human readable this way:

```
from datetime import datetime
n = datetime.now()
n.strftime('output/file_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.txt')
```

Comment: -1 the question is how to figure out whether a resource has changed on the server.

Comment: My question wasn't entirely clear, but time-stamping the filename was mentioned

Comment: this outputs epoch time, any idea how to make it standard (human readable) time/date?

Answer (score -1):

`urllib.urlretrieve()` already does this for you. If the output file name exists, it does all the necessary checks to avoid downloading it again.

But this only works when the server supports it. So you may want to print the HTTP headers (second result of the function call) to see whether caching could be done.

Also this article might help: http://pymotw.com/2/urllib/

It has this code near the end:

```
import urllib
import os

def reporthook(blocks_read, block_size, total_size):
    if not blocks_read:
        print 'Connection opened'
        return
    if total_size < 0:
        # Unknown size
        print 'Read %d blocks' % blocks_read
    else:
        amount_read = blocks_read * block_size
        print 'Read %d blocks, or %d/%d' % (blocks_read, amount_read, total_size)
    return

try:
    filename, msg = urllib.urlretrieve('http://blog.doughellmann.com/', reporthook=reporthook)
    print
    print 'File:', filename
    print 'Headers:'
    print msg
    print 'File exists before cleanup:', os.path.exists(filename)

finally:
    urllib.urlcleanup()

    print 'File still exists:', os.path.exists(filename)
```

This downloads a file, shows the progress and prints the headers. Use it to debug your scenario to find out why caching doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: Hi Aaron, my implementation of urllib.urlretrieve keeps overwriting the files even though the filename is the same. Is there anything I need to do to invoke this feature?

Comment: When you say "overwrite", then so you see it downloading blocks?

Comment: Do you have evidence the urlretrieve does this? The retrieve function in my /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py definitly doesnt. Never looks at the Last-Modified header, never stats the file to get time, to be able to send if-modified-since header, and thereby able to use 304 responces. The only header it uses is Content-Length - to confirm the download matched the expected size. Just blindly opens the URL then writes to the file - not caring if it exists already. Confirmed by looking at webserver logs, as well in code (I control both sides in my example)

Comment: My evidence is the documentation: "If the URL points to a local file [...] the object is not copied."(http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) Maybe the docs are buggy?